# Proving $\arg(a)\equiv \alpha\Longleftrightarrow z_1z_2 \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-geometry

Suppose the complex equation $iz^2+(2-i)az-(1+i)a^2=0$ as $a\in \mathbb{C}^{*}$.

$z_1$ and $z_2$ are the solution of this equation and we have also $z_1*z_2 = a^2(i-1)$.

How can I prove that $\arg(a)\equiv \dfrac{-3\pi}{8}[\dfrac{\pi}{2}]\Longleftrightarrow z_1z_2 \in \mathbb{R} $ ?

Comment: What is the relation in question?

Comment: ok I find the solution.

Comment: You're considering equivalence classes, but I fail to see what is the equivalence relation you're considering. Is it $\mod 2\pi$?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$\begin{eqnarray}
  z_1z_2 \in \mathbb{R} &\Longleftrightarrow& \arg(a^2(i-1))\equiv 0[\pi] \\
&\Longleftrightarrow& 2\arg(a)+arg(i-1)\equiv 0[\pi] \\
&\Longleftrightarrow& 2\arg(a)+\dfrac{3\pi}{4} \equiv 0 [\pi] \\ 
&\Longleftrightarrow& \arg(a) \equiv \dfrac{-3\pi}{8}[\dfrac{\pi}{2}]
\end{eqnarray}$